# Update data in local database in C#

Tags: c#, local-database

I made a local database in visual studio 2013, I dragged my table fields from data source on my form. I just write three lines code for saving data in the table for a button.

```
this.Validate();
this.myBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.myDataSet);
```

My question is I did the same for another application and I can update data records by this button but It shows me an exception for this application when I want to update my data records. I used C# for both application.

Comment: At least you could show us that exception text. Or should we guess it?

Comment: It shows on this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.myDataSet) contains: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in BitaSanatRailiPhoneBOOK.exe

Additional information: Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Comment: Well, exception text is self-explanatory. Your `tableAdapterManager` doesn't has update command configured. Probably it has only select command configured when you dragged it to the form - but code you've provided is not enough to make a final decision.